# Error in database connectivity

Tags: android, json

I am new in android development. am using PHP to connect my android application to mysql, and using "Json" to encoding.i used the following code to get the data,convert response to string
parse JSON data.
But i have an error on this code "JSONArray jArray = null;"
The error is "mainhome(layout) cannot be resolved , or not a field.
java code is as follows.

```
package com.example.bagyourjob;

import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainhome);

        JSONArray jArray = null;
        String result = null;
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        InputStream is = null;


        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        //http post
        try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

             //Why to use 10.0.2.2
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/myfirsttry.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();
             }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
            }
        //convert response to string
        try{
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
               sb = new StringBuilder();
               sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

               String line="0";
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
                }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

        String name;
        try{
              jArray = new JSONArray(result);
              JSONObject json_data=null;
              for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     String ct_name = json_data.getString("NAME");//here "Name" is the column name in database
                 }
              }
              catch(JSONException e1){
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              } catch (ParseException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
         }
        }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

kindly help it.

Comment: Have you created **mainhome.xml** in ur layout folder?

Comment: Yes.i created.a simple layout, named it "mainhome".just for displaying the data from mysql

Comment: Where you are displaying the data in mainhome? no codes found after parsed the json data..

Comment: @Brendon , can you please write the code for displaying the data to my application

Comment: First remove tat import android.R.string from your code and try

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Just **remove** `import android.R.string;` this line

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a Network attempt in a MainActivity which will raise a Exception and force close for your project, so do it using a AsyncTask by doInBackground method..

Learn  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

So far i have seen your code that seems to be incomplete, use parsed the JSON but never used that data thereafter..